# Plotly Mapbox base map: World covid cases - GeoJson file

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to plot a map in Mapbox using Choroplethmapbox to show how many covid cases there are however it doesnt show me anything.

```
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owid/covid-19-data/master/public/data/owid-covid-data.csv")

df= df[df['date']=='2020-12-14']


df.head()


##for plotting


from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
with urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johan/world.geo.json/master/countries.geo.json') as response:
    world = json.load(response)

import plotly.express as px

fig = px.choropleth(df, geojson=world, locations='location', color='total_cases',
                           color_continuous_scale="Viridis",
                           range_color=(0, 12),
                           scope="world",
                           labels={'total_cases':'total covid cases'}
                          )
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

However it doesnt show me anything. Additionaly, I would like to set a min and max:

```
threshold_scale = np.linspace(df['total_cases'].min(),
                              df['total_cases'].max(),
                              6, dtype=int)
threshold_scale = threshold_scale.tolist() # change the numpy array to a list
threshold_scale[-1] = threshold_scale[-1] + 1 # make sure that the last value of the list is greater than the maximum immigration
```

Is it possible to add this to the plot?